# Unpacking and merging lists in a column in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I have the following `data.frame`:

```
id     name   altNames
1001   Joan   character(0)      
1002   Jane   c("Janie", "Janet", "Jan")
1003   John   Jon
1004   Bill   Will
1005   Tom    character(0)
```

The column `altNames` could be empty (i.e. character(0)), have just one name, or a list of names. What I want is a `data.frame` (or a list) where each entry from `name` and/or `altNames` appears just once along with the corresponding `id`, like this:

```
id     name
1001   Joan
1002   Jane
1002   Janie
1002   Janet
1002   Jan
1003   John
1003   Jon
1004   Bill
1004   Will
1005   Tom
```

What's the most efficient way of doing it? Even better is `dplyr` is utilized.
Thanks

Edit: Here's the data:

```
df <- data_frame(
  id = c("1001", "1002","1003", "1004", "1005"), 
  name = c("Joan", "Jane", "John", "Bill", "Tom"), 
  altNames = list(character(0), c("Janie", "Janet", "Jan"), "Jon", "Will", character(0))
)
```

Comment: This is the job of `tidyr::unnest`, but it's currently broken for this example: https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/issues/91

Comment: I get errors using your dput, so I changed it to @hadley's example. here is another way in base r by the way `do.call('rbind', lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) data.frame(id = df[x, 1], name = unlist(df[x, -1]), row.names = NULL)))`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a possible `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, .(name = c(name, unlist(altNames))), by = id]
#       id  name
#  1: 1001  Joan
#  2: 1002  Jane
#  3: 1002 Janie
#  4: 1002 Janet
#  5: 1002   Jan
#  6: 1003  John
#  7: 1003   Jon
#  8: 1004  Bill
#  9: 1004  Will
# 10: 1005   Tom
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the OP got a valid `data.frame` to look like he did. It had to be a `data.table` at some point (or a return from a really hokey function).

Comment: @hrbrmstr it was the output of `jsonlite`

Comment: ugh. it's as bad as having `NULL`s in `data.frame`s. you should definitely move the `jsonlite` output to `data.table` really early on after reading if your source data will be generating this alot.

Comment: This works. Any way to do this with just `dplyr` and `data.frame`? Don't know much about `data.table` and trying to avoid it

Answer (score 10):

A base R version (using the `df` added by @rawr)

```
with(df, {
    ns <- mapply(c, name, altNames)
    data.frame(id = rep(id, times=lengths(ns)), name=unlist(ns), row.names=NULL)
})
#     id  name
#1  1001  Joan
#2  1002  Jane
#3  1002 Janie
#4  1002 Janet
#5  1002   Jan
#6  1003  John
#7  1003   Jon
#8  1004  Bill
#9  1004  Will
#10 1005   Tom
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Gives me wrong id and duplicates. Weird.

Comment: @Amin i don't know, `lengths` is for R 3.2+, but that would just throw an error not give wrong results.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a full dplyr + tidyr solution, the way I'd tackle it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data_frame(
  id = c("1001", "1002","1003", "1004", "1005"), 
  name = c("Joan", "Jane", "John", "Bill", "Tom"), 
  altNames = list(character(0), c("Janie", "Janet", "Jan"), "Jon", "Will", character(0))
)

# Need some way to concatenate a list of vectors with a vectors
# in a "rowwise" way
vector_c <- function(...) {
  Map(c, ...)
}

df %>% 
  mutate(
    names = vector_c(name, altNames),
    altNames = NULL,
    name = NULL
  ) %>% 
  unnest(names)
#> Source: local data frame [10 x 2]
#> 
#>      id names
#> 1  1001  Joan
#> 2  1002  Jane
#> 3  1002 Janie
#> 4  1002 Janet
#> 5  1002   Jan
#> 6  1003  John
#> 7  1003   Jon
#> 8  1004  Bill
#> 9  1004  Will
#> 10 1005   Tom
```

Most of the hard work is done by `tidyr::unnest()`: it's designed to take data frame with a list-column and unnest it, repeating the other columns as needed.

Answer (score 4):

Using `tidyr`, after cleaning the data with `data.table`:

First, fix the data:

```
library(data.table)
dat<-setDT(dat)
dat$altNames[sapply(dat$altNames, length) == 0] <- NA
```

Now `unnest` from `tidyr` and some `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% unnest(altNames) %>%
        group_by(id) %>%
        do(unique(c(.[["name"]],.[["altNames"]])))

     id    V1
1  1001  Joan
2  1001    NA
3  1002  Jane
4  1002 Janie
5  1002 Janet
6  1002   Jan
7  1003  John
8  1003   Jon
9  1004  Bill
10 1004  Will
11 1005   Tom
12 1005    NA
```

it has the NAs, but they are easily removed with `%>% na.omit`.

I think data.table is the winner on this one.