# how to reverse the list operation in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with one column of element list.

```
DT = data.table(A = rep(letters[1:3],2),
                B = list(sample(sample(4,3)), sample(4:10,2), sample(4.2)))

#   A       B
#1: a   3,2,1
#2: b     9,7
#3: c 4,3,2,1
#4: a   3,2,1
#5: b     9,7
#6: c 4,3,2,1
```

How can I convert the list at B column back to individual value, like

```
#    A     B
#    a     3
#    a     2
#    a     1
#    b     9
#    b     7
#    c     4
#    c     3
#    c     2
#    c     1
#   and go on
```

Comment: Try `library(tidyverse);DT %>% unnest` or `DT[, .(B = unlist(B)), A]`

Comment: Given that you do not want to repeat the list elements, use `DT[, unique(unlist(B)), by=A]`

Comment: @arg0naut Could this be it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31195925/unpacking-and-merging-lists-in-a-column-in-data-frame

Comment: Or this (since `data.table` is the focus): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44336733/how-to-unlist-a-column-in-a-data-table ; it'd be slightly different if OP really doesn't want to repeat the list elements, but the description of question is not clear on that

Comment: @arg0naut Thanks for finding more reference. I will keep this post for a while until I finish reading your suggestion. Thanks, guys.